# Steam tag icon pngs are blank

Tags: javascript, html, steam, steam-web-api

Here's my situation: I'm scraping HTML from Steam's game pages to collect tag information for various games. Ideally I would use Steam's Web API to collect these tags, but they don't support that...

So here's an example for TF2: from `http://store.steampowered.com/app/440` I've scraped and compiled these tags into JSON:

```
{"steam_tags": [
  {
    "iconUrl": "http://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/v6/ico/ico_multiPlayer.png",
    "name": "Multi-player"
  },
  {
    "icon_url": "http://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/v6/ico/ico_multiPlayer.png",
    "name": "Cross-Platform Multiplayer"
  },
  {
    "icon_url": "http://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/v6/ico/ico_achievements.png",
    "name": "Steam Achievements"
  },
  {
    "icon_url": "http://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/v6/ico/ico_cards.png",
    "name": "Steam Trading Cards"
  },
  {
    "icon_url": "http://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/v6/ico/ico_cc.png",
    "name": "Captions available"
  },
  {
    "icon_url": "http://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/v6/ico/ico_workshop.png",
    "name": "Steam Workshop"
  }
]}
```

**The problem is that these image links, which come directly from the HTML source, appear blank in any browser.**

Am I missing something obvious? I feel like this shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: I think they are just white.  I checked the last one and it showed up.

Comment: Opening a PNG in Photoshop reveals that it's a white graphic with a transparent background. You need to display it on a dark background.

Comment: Those are white icons, they will always be "invisible" if your background is white as well xD

Comment: Voting to close as this is not actually a programming issue.

Comment: So it was something super obvious... thanks for your help!